# call an action in a form inside phtml magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, registration

I created a new form registration for customer under my `theme/magento_Customer` then i created a new module and i created a new function in the block calling the new action but when inspecting the action in form is empty and when filling the data in form nothing happen i still in same page here is my code :

```
<?php
namespace Mdweb\Inscription\Block;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;


class Register extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param EncoderInterface $urlEncoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface|null $urlDecoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\HostChecker|null $hostChecker
     */
    public function __construct(

        RequestInterface $request,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface $urlDecoder = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\HostChecker $hostChecker = null
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;

        $this->urlDecoder = $urlDecoder ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface::class);
        $this->hostChecker = $hostChecker ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Url\HostChecker::class);
    }


    public function getHelloWorldTxt()
    {
        return 'Hello world!';
    }

    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return 'newcust/account/createcustomer' ;
    }

}
```

and my action :

```
<?php   
namespace Mdweb\Inscription\Controller\Account;
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class CreateCustomer  extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    private $customerRepository;
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_request = $request;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            if (isset($_POST['contact_person'])) {

                $this->_request->getPost();

                // Instantiate object (this is the most important part)

                $custom = $this->customerFactory->create();
                $custom->setFirstname('vide');
                $custom->setLastname('vide');
                $custom->setPassword($_POST['password']);
                $custom->setWebsiteId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                $custom->loadByEmail($_POST['email']);
                $custom->setGroupId(4);
                $custom->setTelephone('telephone');


                // Main code to resolve this issue.

                $customerData = $custom->getDataModel();
                $customerData->setCustomAttribute('client_code', 'vide');
                $customerData->setCustomAttribute('contact_person', $_POST['contact_person']);
                $customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_status', $_POST['customer_status']);

                $customerData->setCustomAttribute('web_site', $_POST['web_site']);


                $custom->updateData($customerData);
                var_dump($custom->updateData($customerData));
                die('please tele me where is the erreur');
                $custom->save();

                echo 'Customer is successfully created.';

                // Save data

                //$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


}
```

and that's how i called the new function in my new form

```
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
```

any help please and thanks in advance

Comment: Update you xml and full form.

Comment: how to do that ??

Comment: Please add the code of your layout `xml` file to review

Comment: <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register_2" template="Magento_Customer::form/register2.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>

Comment: the form 2 is same the register.phtml and i added some custom attributs but i can't add the address i tried ti setshowAddrees(true) but no result

Comment: change block class name in layout file to use your class function

Comment: what block ?? i did not understnad you

Comment: <block class="Mdweb\Inscription\Block\Register" name="customer_form_register_2" template="Magento_Customer::form/register2.phtml">

Comment: when i changed this i am getting thi erreur

Comment: Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in /var/www/html/Selecta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:652 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Selecta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() #1 /var/www/html/Selecta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('customer_form_r...') #2 /var/www/html/Selecta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout-